# Почему в проекте можно обратится к зависимостям подключенной dll?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, архитектура

Всем привет!Сразу извиняюсь, если очень глупо задал вопрос.

Суть проблемы:

Практикую трехслойную архитектуру. DAL->BLL->WEB. Все зависимости идут по порядку.

Однако, когда я добавил в слой WEB ссылку на BLL. Этот слой стал давать возможность обращаться к DAL слою. Подскажите в чем проблема. Все слои делаются на .net core 2.2.

[image: Скриншот проблемы]

Comment: Подключая dll, вы неявно подключаете все её зависимости. Так задумано.

Comment: @PashaPash а как же тогда ограничить доступ к этому слою? Ведь слой представления не должен знать о слое доступа к данным.

Comment: Не должен знать == "в коде не должно быть вызовов". Просто не вызывайте его, всего делов.

Comment: @PashaPash странно... Т.е. и в больших проектах такое встречается и приходится надеется на компетентность разработчика чтобы он не стал на прямую обращаться к слою с данными?

Comment: Ну есть ещё инструменты в той же студии для обнаружения layer skipping, есть код ревью. Но в общем - несколько странно доверять человеку писать код в проекте, но при этом не доверять ему самостоятельно следовать гайдлайнам :)

Comment: @PashaPash ок, спасибо!)Просто я еще довольно далек от разработки крупных проектов и не видел в живую, как работает разработка при трехслойной архитектуре. И прочитав пару книжек с довольно легкими примерами, встретился с такой ситуацией, когда в книгах говорится, что слой представления не должен знать о слое с данными, а в живую, у меня есть возможность с помощью using подключится к слою DAL. Возможно такую архитектуру нужно принимать как абстракцию и просто в голове знать о том, что нужно общаться только со слоем BLL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам уже ответили в комментариях @PashaPash, давайте оформим ответом:

> Подключая dll, вы неявно подключаете все её зависимости. Так задумано.

Также вы спрашиваете:

> слой представления не должен знать о слое с данными

У вас есть слой DAL и BLL, но не выделен слой Domain.

Если вы в домен вынесете модели и интефейсы, то BLL не будет зависеть от конкретной реализации DAL, а будет вся на интерфейсах и в WEB вы можете подключать BLL и какую-то конкретную реализацию DAL (их может быть несколько - dal на EF, dal на dapper).

Конкретный пример такого приложения есть в книге Марка Симана Dependency Injection in c#

На гитхабе есть этот проект, см. тут: https://github.com/djhmateer/3Commerce.git

Делая по такому шаблону вы можете дойти до такого момента, что у вас не останется в WEB никаких ссылок на DAL, лишь только в конфигурационном файле будет строкой прописано какой DAL подключить.

На практике я обычно применяю менее строгий подход: у меня подключен проект конкретного DAL'а, но в проекте WEB ссылка на него фигурирует лишь один раз: я указываю при resolve зависимостей саму сборку.

```
        var dataAccessAssembly = typeof(DataContext).Assembly;
```

Меня такой подход вполне устраивает: и гайдланы соблюдены и если вдруг понадобится (ни разу не понадобилось) поменять конкретную реализацию DAl то сделать это будет достаточно просто.

Comment: Спасибо вам и @PashaPash  за помощь в решении моих вопросов! Буду сейчас изучать указанную вами книгу и проект)